# Dynamically adjust the weighting of columns in a row based on string length

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I have a layout with two texts, one on left side and one on right side. If both texts are long, left one should occupy 60%, and right one 40% of the width. But if right text is shorter than 40%, the left one should take all the available space.

Here are the examples:
[image: long right part]
and:
[image]
So I would like to write something like this:

```
Row {
    Text(text = left, modifier = modifier.padding(8.dp).weight(<min 0.6f>))
    Text(text = right, modifier = modifier.padding(8.dp).weight(<max 0.4f>))
}
```

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally, I figured it out. Here is the modifier:

```
fun Modifier.maxWidth(
    fraction: Float = 1f,
) = layout { measurable, constraints ->
    val maxWidth = (constraints.maxWidth * fraction).roundToInt()
    val width = measurable.maxIntrinsicWidth(constraints.maxHeight).coerceAtMost(maxWidth)

    val placeable = measurable.measure(Constraints(constraints.minWidth, width, constraints.minHeight, constraints.maxHeight))
    layout(width, placeable.height) {
        placeable.placeRelative(0, 0)
    }
}
```

So we can use it like this:

```
Row {
    Text(text = left, modifier = modifier.padding(8.dp).weight(1f)) // left text uses all the available space
    Text(text = right, modifier = modifier.padding(8.dp).maxWidth(fraction = 0.4f)) // right text can be 40% of the parent or less
}
```

Comment: I have a use where left and right text can wrap their texts, but when the overlapping cases occur, the left should be 60 and right should be 40. How to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Measure the length of each string and calculate their weights. Adjust the weights based on the maximum allowed for the right column:

```kotlin
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        startActivity(intent)

        val paint = android.graphics.Paint()

        // First row
        val text1 = "This long text should take up maximum 60% of the space with wrapping"
        val text2 = "This is not very long"

        val width1 = paint.measureText(text1)
        val width2 = paint.measureText(text2)

        var w2 = width2 / (width1 + width2)

        if (w2 > 0.4f) {
            w2 = 0.4f
        }

        val w1 = 1f - w2

        // Second row
        val text3 = "This text should take up more than 60% of the space"
        val text4 = "Short"

        val width3 = paint.measureText(text3)
        val width4 = paint.measureText(text4)

        var w4 = width4 / (width3 + width4)

        if (w4 > 0.4f) {
            w4 = 0.4f
        }

        val w3 = 1f - w4

        setContent {
            Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
                Row(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .wrapContentHeight()
                        .padding(bottom = 20.dp)
                ) {
                    Text(text1, modifier = Modifier.weight(w1))
                    Text(text2, modifier = Modifier.weight(w2), color = Color.Red)
                }

                Row(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .wrapContentHeight()
                        .padding(bottom = 20.dp)
                ) {
                    Text(text3, modifier = Modifier.weight(w3))
                    Text(text4, modifier = Modifier.weight(w4), color = Color.Red)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```